# Error (Xcode): Framework not found flutter_image_compress while trying to build flutter app

Tags: ios, flutter, codemagic

I have recently added the flutter_image_compress package to my project and it works well on Android but when I am trying to build ios app through code magic, I face this error :

```
Error (Xcode): Framework not found flutter_image_compress
```

also here is code magic pre-build script :

```
flutter clean
rm ios/Pod
flutter pub get
flutter pub deps
cd ios
rm podfile.lock
pod deintegrate
pod repo update
pod install
pod update
flutter clean
agvtool new-version -all 36
agvtool new-marketing-version 1.1.6
```

Comment: were you able to solve it? I can see open issue in `flutter_image_compress` repo without any attention :( https://github.com/fluttercandies/flutter_image_compress/issues/230